# cannot find file error when executing remote command over ssh(paramiko)

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to create a vm using pythhon and proxmoxer api.Issue is that when i try to ruun qmrestore command the OS image is not found,which is actually present at the location(mount point)

```
import paramiko
from proxmoxer import ProxmoxAPI
import re
vmid=1000
image_name='Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar\n'.strip()
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
target_host = 'x.x.x.x'
target_port = 22
target_port = 22
pwd = ':)'
un = 'root'
ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password = pwd )
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd //vmstore;ls')
for files in stdout:
    image=re.match(files.strip(),'Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar',re.I)
    #print image_name
    if image:
        print "Image found"
        #mage_name=image
        break
    else:
        flag=0
print "Inn try"
print image_name
command=r'qmrestore '+image_name + " " + '11111'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print stdout.readlines()
print stderr.readlines()
```

Output:

```
print stdout.readlines()
[]
stderr.readlines()
[u"can't find file 'Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar'\n"]
```

Comment: It seems like you are looking for one specific file... so why list the whole directory?

Comment: The problem is with the ssh.exec_command(command).The command does not run on the remote mamchine,while the same command runs manually.

Comment: Your `re.match` is backwards... the pattern should be first and the string second. But it seems like `'Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar' in files` would work also.

Comment: Lets step back a bit. Are you looking for that one file specifically? If so, your command could be `if [ -a /vmstore/Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar ]; then echo FOUND; fi` and then look for "FOUND" in the output stream.

Comment: Your script doesn't produce the output you claim. The command `'cd //vmstore;ls'` wouldn't give the error `u"can't find file 'Ubuntu14.04_DT64bit.tar'\n"` because you didn't give that file name in the command. We seem to be dealing with different scripts here.

Comment: tdelaney,we are dealing with a python script here.You are posting a shel script code.i am listing all files in vmstore directory,then finding the image.Now the next step is to run the qmrestore command with the image.Thats where i am getting nothing on the standard output.

Comment: You are talking to a shell on the other side. I didn't realize you were talking about the second exec_command. Your first one fails so I kinda assumed. The problem on the second one is that you are not in the right directory. Each exec_command is a new shell and needs to be cd'd again - or use absolute path.

Comment: Thanks tdelaney.That solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko's `exec_command` creates a channel and executes a remote shell to run its command. The remote shell and channel are closed when the command completes. This has the advantage that the command response is delimited by the closed channel and any given command is independent of other commands that may be in progress on other channels. But this also means that any environmental change in one command does not persist. In this case, you must change directories on all of the commands, not just the first.